# Show regional chars in android

Tags: java, android, char, toast

I have method :

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) 
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(event.getCharacters()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ShowKeyboardSystem(false);
    Find(event.getCharacters());
    return true;
}
```

Unfortunately toast does show regional chars. Why?

Comment: *Regional chars*? What do you mean? And what's `Find()`?

Comment: Find a method that searches for the character string given as parameter

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Comment: This is not a solution to my problem. I need to capture regional characters from the keyboard and compared with the previously entered by the user

Comment: Do you actually mean **non-english** characters? The answering your question, the Toast shows *regional* characters because `event.getCharacters()` has *regional* characters... You didn't specify what you want to do...

Comment: Problem is solve. thanks very much

Comment: @ArturSiwek post the solution so others with similar problem can look upto your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can display custom toast with typeface set for the text in toast. I have downloaded kn.ttf(typeface for kannada which is local langauage where i reside) and put the same in assests folder as shown in the image below.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

custom alyout for toast

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:padding="8dp"
          android:background="#DAAA"
          >
 <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="#FFF"
          />
 </LinearLayout>
```

The code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView myTextView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom,
                                           (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

            TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            text.setText("This is a custom toast");
            Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/kn.ttf");
            text.setTypeface(typeFace);
            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(layout);
            toast.show();
        }

    });

}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this work on Android 4.0 (ICS) ? I am not able to show Kannada characters in my application. Please check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455923/kannada-font-on-android-ics