# Kannada Font on Android ICS

Tags: android, fonts, typeface, android-fonts, kannada

I am supporting Tamil and Kannada fonts in my application.
I use the following code to set the typeface of TextViews, Buttons, etc

```
FONT_TAMIL = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/tamil.ttf");
tvTitle.setTypeface(FONT_TAMIL);

FONT_KANNADA = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/kannada.ttf");
tvTitle.setTypeface(FONT_KANNADA);
```

I am able to display Tamil characters properly even on GingerBread. But I am not able to show the Kannada font. Can anyone please help me to find where I am going wrong?

An example screenshot of Tamil..
[image: Tamil]

An example screenshot of Kannada..
[image: Kannada]

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: what is the problem exactly? You need to elaborate.

Comment: post screen shots that will give us a better idea

Comment: Me facing same issue with Hindi font. The best way I have found by looking at other apps in the play store is to use images (stretchable one's). Since creating such images will require time. I have published my app for the higher android versions and planning to release for lower ones later on.

Comment: @Anup and Raghunandan Please see the screenshots.

Comment: @Sandeep My application supports Tamil for long time. Now I added Kannada. I think I should restrict ICS for Kannada if I don't find a solution.

Comment: Font support on older androids is very poor, best strategy is to publish your app for tested androids as of now and work on making it compatible with older versions. BTW, does your kannada font displays fine on jelly bean?

Comment: Yes. It is absolutely fin on JellyBean. If it doesn't work on Gingerbread, that's fine. But I want it to work on atleast ICS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried replaceAll function to replace each and every Unicode characters to Ascii? You can use Character Map tool in Windows to  get the equivalent ASCII characters for each of your Kannada/Tamil characters.

1) First you install both Unicode and Kannada font in your PC.

2) Then open two windows of character map tool.Select Unicode font in first window and Ascii in second one.

3) In both windows, double click the desired characters (same character in both windows).So the character will be displayed in the textbox.Copy that character from both windows and add them to replaceAll function.

Its  takes long to copy each and every characters and character combinations.But I dont think there is another method to display unicode properly below ICS version.You need to convert it.And ofcourse hardwork leads to success :) Best wishes bro...

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit more how to use character map tool?

Comment: Hi, Am really sorry for bugging you Basim. Please clarify this doubt. The tool shows Kannada characters when i select "BRH Kannada" but I guess those characters are just raw characters. I know only tamil. So, for example, the tools shows Oo (ஊ) and Ka (க) but not Koo (கூ). But I need to replace Koo with some ASCII characters I guess. Do you understand what I am saying? Please ping me endless.karthikp@gmail.com

Comment: For Koo, try the combinations of Ka and Oo. means, ka+Oo (without + symbol).Then you will get the correct combinations of characters for the word Koo.Similiarly for the combination, Kee try the combination of Ka and Ee (Ka+Ee). When you select a Kannada Unicode font make sure that it contain all the characters and combinations.If its not, try another Kannada unicode font.